# JPA self-join issue, how can I only get the 1st level reference?

Tags: java, ebean

I have a Person table with a column named *CREATEBY*. It's reference column is Person's *ID*.

How can I only get the 1st level reference?

This is Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "cname")
    private String cname;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "createby", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Person createby;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }

    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }

    public Person getCreateby() {
        return createby;
    }

    public void setCreateby(Person createby) {
        this.createby = createby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", cname=" + cname + ", createby="
                + createby + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is the test case

```
public class SelfJoinTest extends ExampleBaseTestCase {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setId(1);
        p1.setCname("p1");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setId(2);
        p2.setCname("p2");
        p2.setCreateby(p1);

        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setId(3);
        p3.setCname("p3");
        p3.setCreateby(p2);

        Ebean.save(p1);
        Ebean.save(p2);
        Ebean.save(p3);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Person p = Ebean.find(Person.class, 3);
        System.out.println(p);

        // jackson
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere says use the Jackson annotations to solve it, but I think it is not the best way. This way waste many DB queries. Does JPA have a solution for this?

Comment: What happens if you add `fetch = fetchType.LAZY` and `optional = false` to the `@OneToOne` association?

Comment: I tried, and do not work. When jackson serialize the person object, it will call the GETTER method.

Comment: Which implies that the test is within the same transaction as the `find`. Can you add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` to the `test()` method? You need to be able to 'detach' the `p` object from the persistence context.

Comment: Hi DuncanKinnear, thanks for quickly post. the TX way is not work too. Assuming that works, the 1st level will not been queried too.

Comment: Yes, a quick bit of research into how EBean works tells me that it doesn't have sessions, so therefore objects do not get detached. This is the problem with using frameworks that are supposed to 'make things simple' - you lose a certain amount of control over what they do. So, it looks like you will probably have to go the `@JsonIgnore` way with the `@OneToOne` association.

Comment: Yes, maybe the breakthrough is Jackson. But the `@JsonIgnore` annotation is not the solution, also the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` pair. Because if I use them, the 1st level reference is ignored too. Maybe another JSON framework can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution now. And I awake to that THE JPA SHOULD NOT HANDLE THIS SITUATION, and even the jackson. There is something wrong with my pattern.

As the problem's POJO, I should use **open session in view** pattern, but it is not suit for me.

So, I made a DTO named `PersonWithoutCreateby`, which not contains `createby` field.

And in `Person`, the `createby` field changed to `private PersonWithoutCreateby createby;`. And transfer the `Person` to view.